# How do I create a custom file format on mac?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I want to create a file type that contains objective c code and image data. But I want it not readable by a text editor. How best do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already know how to append the code and the image in a file (which, however, should be a pretty easy task), you just need to crypt the data before storing. You can easily do it using, i.e., [AES](https://github.com/nicerobot/objc/tree/master/NSData/NSData%2BAES/) encryption.

Comment: What I mean is I want it only readable by my application. Won't encryption not work as the key needs to be stored for decryption?

Comment: Well, of course your app must know (in some way) the key needed to decrypt the file. And, of course, anybody else having the key would be able as well to read the file. Remember that, anything you do, your encrypted file needs to be decrypted, thus anybody else having enough informations to decrypt (key/algorithm used) will be able to read the original content (unless you hash it, but this way nobody will be able to read it's original content, not even you).